# Physical Interpretation of the Bloch vector

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

In the expression of the density matrix of a (Electron-Spin) Qubit
$$
\rho=\frac{1}{2}(I + x \sigma_x + y \sigma_y + z \sigma_z)
$$
where $\tau=(x,y,z)$ is unit vector in the [Bloch sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_sphere), which is the physical Interpretation of $\tau$? Can it be interpreted as the direction of spin axis of the electron?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performing explicit but trivial computations, it turns out that (assuming $\hbar=1$):  $$\tau/2 = (\langle S_x\rangle_\rho, \langle S_y\rangle_\rho, \langle S_z\rangle_\rho)$$
So $\tau/2$ describes the **expectation values** of the three components of the spin 
when the system is in the, generally, mixed, state $\rho$.

Indeed:
$$\langle S_k \rangle_\rho := tr\left(\frac{1}{2} \sigma_k \frac{1}{2}(I + \sum_{i=1}^3x_i \sigma_i)\right) = \frac{1}{4}\left( tr \sigma_k + \sum_{k=1}^3 x_itr(\sigma_k \sigma_i)\right)= \frac{1}{4}\left(0 + \sum_{i=1}^3 2 x_i \delta_{ik} \right) = \frac{1}{2} x_k\:.$$